# How to pass a variable with href url?

Tags: python, html, flask-mail

Below is my code to send email using flask in python.

```
def sendPasswordResetLink(email, token):
    message = Message()
    message.subject = "Reset your password"
    message.sender = "********@gmail.com"
    message.recipients = email.split()
    message.html = '<p>Hello there,</p>\n' \
                   '<p>Please click on the below link to reset your password</p>\n' \
                   '<a href=http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token= +token+>'
    mail.send(message)
```

Something is wrong in `<a href....` line. It is not printing anything in the mail which I am getting. Im using flask-mail extenstion. Can someone give me a quick fix for this.
As i said im using flask-mail extension which provides provides a simple interface to set up SMTP with our Flask application and to send messages from our views and scripts.

expected behavior - It should send a mail to my gmail with subject "Reset your password" and in mail body I should get 
Hello there,
Please click on the below link to reset your password.
http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token=2

token is a parameter which im sending along with function definition. It contains the userid of the one who requests for the reset password.
But the URL is not getting printed in mail which Im getting.

Comment: So something's wrong? Cool.. Mind telling us what it is? :) (And while you're at it, what is `mail` as it's never defined, did you mean to write `email.send(...)`, guessing not but still, it's undefined?

Comment: Sorry, Actually I had explained the issue I don't know why only remaining part is cropped.
"Something is wrong in <a href.... line. It is not printing anything in the mail. Can someone give me a quick fix for this. " -> this was my explanation.
mail is not defined but I am using flask-mail extension so I think it will be there by default.

Comment: Ah, because stackoverflow allows you to create HTML tags (like `<br>` for line breaks etc). There for, it assumed it would find `>` some where down the line since you started the `<a` tag.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I edited it now. But if you know the solution for the question can you please help.

Comment: Short answer: Nope. Because I don't know what you mean by *"not printing anything in the mail"*, what does it look like and what's the expected behavior? And what is `mail`? I'm guessing it's something to do with how flask sends e-mails but again, no idea what you're receiving.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry for not giving enough info

Comment: But instead you're getting?

Comment: Im just getting
Hello there,
Please click on the below link to reset your password

Comment: Ah, but not the link part? Is that's what you're trying to say? Because you said "I would like to get 'please click the link' but i'm getting 'please click the link'" :P

Comment: http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token=2
this link im not getting, this is what i mean

Comment: Did you mean to write `<a href="http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token=' + token + '">`? And you mean you get the link, but not the `token` part?

Comment: i tried writing it in the way you said but still im not getting the expected result. 
no not just token part, whole url only is not getting displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sendPasswordResetLink(email, token):
    message = Message()
    message.subject = "Reset your password"
    message.sender = "********@gmail.com"
    message.recipients = email.split()
    message.html = '<p>Hello there,</p>\n' \
                   '<p>Please click on the below link to reset your password</p>\n' \
                   '<a href="http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token=' + token + '">Some message here</a>'
    mail.send(message)
```

Your problem is that you don't escape the `'...'` string and thus never add `token` into the mix. But you're also not ending the `<a>` tag with a `</a>`. And there for there's no message. Here's some [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).